# Se puede cambiar el valor NEW en un BEFORE UPDATE en base SQLite

Tags: sqlite3

este es el codigo que deseo implementar pero me da errores:

```
1  CREATE TRIGGER tg_b_u_table1
2  BEFORE UPDATE ON table1
3  FOR EACH ROW
4  BEGIN 
5  :NEW.dato_int := 5;
6  END;
```

Me marca en rojo la linea 5